# Background image won't show when hover in css

Tags: html, css

Got this code to work with:

```
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #hallo {
            width: 960px;
            height: 600px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            border: solid 1px yellow;
        }
        #bg {
            width: 960px;
            height: 600px;
            position: absolute;
            background-image:url(torres.jpg);
            background-size: 960px 600px;
        }

        #t1 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute; 
            background-size: 100px 100px;
            border: solid 1px white;
        }

        #t1  {
            top: 100px;
            left: 600px;
            background-image:url(torres1.jpg);
        }

        #t1:hover ~ #bg {
            position: absolute;
            background-image:url(torres1.jpg);
            background-size: 960px 600px;
        }


    </style>

<section id="hallo">

    <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="t1"></div>

</section>
```

But I got a problem. When I take the mouseover the t1 div nothing happens. The background-image won't change to "torres1.jpg". Is there any solutions?

I'm noe able to use java for this.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined a `:hover` state for the `#t1` element:

```
#t1  { /* non-hovered */
    top: 100px;
    left: 600px;
}

#t1:hover { /* hovered-over */
    background-image:url(torres1.jpg);
}
```

Edited in response to comment from OP:

> Ah, you don't understand my question. What I am looking for is that the `background-image` in `#bg` to change when hover over the `#t1` div.

This *can't* happen ([yet](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject)), CSS can *only* affect elements that appear in the DOM *later* than the current element on whose interaction you're trying to style it.

Therefore while you *could* style `#t1` based on the `#bg:hover`, but you *cannot* style a parent, or previous-sibling, based on the `:hover` of a child or later-sibling.

Comment: Ah, you don't understand my question. What I am looking for is that the background-image in #bg to change when hover over the #t1 div.

Comment: Okei, so if I want it to work I need to put the #t1 before the #bg ? How about the position then?

Comment: Like David Thomas said, you can't do that in CSS alone, but I think it can be done using javascript

Comment: What do you mean "how about the position"?

Comment: When I swap #bg and #t1 I am unable to position the #bg div.

Answer (score 0):

Swap `#bg` and `#t1` and your sibling selector should work:

```
<section id="hallo">
    <div id="t1"></div>
    <div id="bg"></div>
</section>
```